# Trigger an action for each hit of Elasticsearch query in Kibana Monitor

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Is it possible to trigger an action for each hit of a given query in a Kibana Monitor? I would like to use a foreach loop to do this as demonstrated [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/action-foreach.html). However, it's unclear how to implement this on the Kibana Monitor page. On the page there is an input field for Trigger Conditions but I'm unsure how to format the foreach within it or if this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

- Consider using Elasticsearch watcher (require at least gold licesnse): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/how-watcher-works.html

Watcher will run on a certain interval and will perform a query against indices (according to your configuration). You will need to create a condition (e.g. hits number is greater than 5) that when it evaluates to true an action will be performed. Elasticsearch allows you to use multiple actions. For example, you can use webhook and receive the data from the last watcher run (you can also use watcher api to transform the data). If you don't have Gold license you can mimic watcher behavior by a script/program that uses Elasticsearch Search API.

Herbeby is a simple example of a watcher checking index named test every minute and sends a webhook with the entire search context in case there is at least one document.

```
{
  "trigger" : {
    "schedule" : { "interval" : "1m" } 
  },
  "input" : {
    "search" : {
      "request" : {
        "indices" : [ "test" ],
        "body" : {
          "query" : {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "range": {
                        "updatedAt": {
                            "gte": "now-1m"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition" : {
    "compare" : { "ctx.payload.hits.total" : { "gt" : 0 }}
  },
  "actions" : { 
    "sample_webhook" : {
      "webhook" : {
        "method" : "POST",
        "url": "http://b4022015b928.ngrok.io/UtilsService/api/elasticHandler/watcher",
        "body" : "{{#toJson}}ctx.payload{{/toJson}}",
        "auth": {
            "basic": {
                "user": "user",
                "password": "pass"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- An alternative way would be to use Kibana Alerts and Actions.
  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alerting-getting-started.html
  This feature is slightly different from Watcher but basically allows you to perfrom actions upon a query against Elasticsearch. This featrue is only part of Kibana opposing to watcher which is part of Elasticsearch (though it is accessible from Kibana stack management).